# Grub2 How to Update Version of Grub?

Tags: grub2

I am Using Ubuntu 18.04 dual boot with windows10.

**Question: how to know the present grub verison via terminal? blue color grub appeared automatically when i did something with "Boot-Repair, how can i update to version 2.02 or latest verison??**

[image: GRUB]

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Upgrading

Comment: This is your version and it should automatically be the newest for your version of Ubuntu. It looks like they are making changes for 18.10 
` grub-install --version` and my 18.04 shows this:
grub-install (GRUB) 2.02-2ubuntu8

Comment: @oldfred i was working with Ubuntu 18.04 fine, it was always purple background..i saw this blue color screen when i did something with Boor-Repair..i have gone through above link but not succeeded.

Comment: You can change colors at will. Just do not do white characters on white background or black chars on black background. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen

Comment: @oldfred i want to know the commands that shows current grub version. and then to update grub to higher version.

Comment: What does this show? ` grub-install --version` The only way to get newer version is to down load & compile the latest grub.  You might be able to get a newer Ubuntu configuration of grub, from 18.10, but otherwise you ahve newest.

Comment: @oldfred pratap@i7-6550U:~$ grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.02-2ubuntu8.1 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Mac.png

Comment: Yours is newer than mine, but I use a local repository that may be a day behind.

Comment: actually i have given some commands in the 1st link given by Kulfy.